# questions about pack of cards

Tags: probability

We are arranging randomly pack of cards.

a. What is the probability that the sequence '9 of diamonds','10  of diamonds' and 'jack of diamonds' will appear  exactly in this order?

b. What is the probability that the sequence '9 of diamonds','10  of diamonds' and 'jack of diamonds' will appear exactly in this order, but the sequence '2 of spades', '3 of spades', '4 of spades' and '5 of spades' will not?

The first question- I've solved by joining the 3 cards together. Then I have '50' cards in the pack
$$\frac{50!}{52!}$$

In the second question I did the same way but I don't think it is right...because I think the events are dependent. I've tried also  to separate this event to stages. In the first stage, I've chosen the place of 9 of diamonds-I have 50 options for that. Then the places of '10  of diamonds' and 'jack of diamonds'are automatically determined. Then I've chosen the place of 2 of spades'-i have 49 
options for that.for '3 of spades' I have 47 options and for the rest of the cards I've got 47! options. is this calculation right? Is there any better way to solve this question?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: It's the probability that the Diamonds come in order minus the probability that both the Diamonds and Spades come in order.

Comment: Assuming that the cards must appear consecutively, you could subtract the number of sequences in which both the sequences $9\diamondsuit, 10\diamondsuit, J\diamondsuit$ and  $2\spadesuit, 3\spadesuit, 4\spadesuit, 5\spadesuit$ appear from the number of sequences in which $9\diamondsuit, 10\diamondsuit, J\diamondsuit$ appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that the cards must appear consecutively~

Your first way is correct.

The second question, you have $47!$ ways of having *both* '9 of diamonds','10 of diamonds' and 'jack of diamonds' and '2 of spades', '3 of spades', '4 of spades' and '5 of spades' in these orders, again by "joining" these to make two big "cards".

Thus the chance is just

$$\frac{50!-47!}{52!}$$

Answer (score 0):

Dan I am studying with you in TAU, contact me to have the full answer...I asked our tutor (N.Y- initials of him)  about it and my answer is correct....
Its 47! becuase you are combining between the spades "card" and the "hearts" card.... so it makes 47!... (Rest of the answer I will give you in class, very long to write and explain)